# Integration by substitution on surface

Tags: integration, surfaces

Suppose I have an integral on the boundary of a Lipschitz domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} f(x-y)dS$$.
where $dS$ is the surface element $dS = g(x)dx$.

Can I do a substitution like this: let $z:=x-y$. Then $dz = dx$, so we have
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} f(x-y)dS = \int_{\partial\Omega} f(z)dS'$$
where $dS =  g(z+y)dz$, because $dS = g(x)dx = g(z+y)dz$.
Is this all I need to think about? I guess not, do I need to change the domain of integration too?

Comment: You used $f$ to denote both the function and the surface element.  Was this a typo?  Anyway, you will need to change the domain of integration.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was a typo. I guess it may be better for me to move to charts and then change variables.